# In django + nginx + wsgi, what is a "mysite.sock"

Tags: django, nginx

I followed [this doc](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html), and almost everything went well untill "mysite.sock" occurred. It occurred like this:

```
server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
# server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
```

This doc did not mention anything about the "mysite.sock" and after one day's searching, I found nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not an expert in this area but I have deployed Django using uWSGI on Nginx with this method. A socket file represents a Unix socket. In this case, uWSGI creates it and it will be through this socket that uWSGI and Nginx will talk to each other.

The "[Concept](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#concept)" section of the link you provided talks about it:

> uWSGI is a WSGI implementation. In this tutorial we will set up uWSGI
>   so that it creates a Unix socket, and serves responses to the web
>   server via the WSGI protocol. At the end, our complete stack of
>   components will look like this:
>
> the web client <-> the web server <-> the socket <-> uwsgi <-> Django

The first part of the tutorial talks about using TCP port socket to achieve the same result. If you have already followed those steps then you should skip the Unix socket part. However, it also mentions that [Unix sockets are better due to less overhead](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#using-unix-sockets-instead-of-ports).

Comment: I don't know what should I write in the mysite.sock. Do you know what does it looks like?

Comment: uWSGI will create the socket file when it starts so you don't need to worry about creating or editing it. Just make sure uWSGI and Nginx have read and write permissions inside the directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will tell you when I made it!

Comment: Finally I did it, with an empty XXXX.sock file in my root directory. Tnank you very much!